# Find matching records between 2 collection variables from 2 different custom objects in Flow to prevent dupe records?

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, duplicate-matching-rule, collection-variable

**Background**: I'm building a flow that bulk creates conference registrations for Custom Object 2 (COB2) using partial data from registrations in Custom Object 1 (COB1). The end user will clean and finalize Conference XYZ data in COB1 and then run the flow 1 time to create all necessary COB2 records for that conference.

**Issue**: Preventing duplicate COB2 records if flow must run more than once for Conference XYZ  (ex: user needs to add an extra COB1 records to COB2 post-fact).

Matching rules won't work bc both COB1 & COB2 are installed packages & the 1 field that's an identical match between them (email) is in different data types on each. Right now, I have the flow ticking a checkbox & updating the original COB1 records upon initial run so it can filter them out next time it runs. I'm not fully happy with this solution, want to avoid having a dedicated field just for this.

I'm trying to find **a way to have the flow handle the de-duping/matching**. I'm a novice so I don't know if having the flow handle this is even possible/a good idea due to gov limits. **Is this actually a job for APEX?**

**My flow thus far**:

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at unofficialsf for a solution?  Specifically https://unofficialsf.com/compare-contrast-two-record-collections-with-findcommonanduncommonrecords/

Comment: @NickCook - Hi Nick, I've actually been staring at that page for a few days now - the fact that there's installation involved gives me pause, I've never done that before/not sure of the risks. Have you worked with this package/recommend it?

Comment: Yes, i've used it extensively and I'd highly recommend it.  The unofficialsf site is run by salesforce engineers and is intended to fill some of the common gaps in Flow